# Initial Navigation Hover state not displaying properly with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, navigation

The initial navigation state is not highlighted on my site:
http://nothingness.co
When it first loads the top button on the left should be highlighted
I have spent 2 hours trying to manipulate the jquery without success.
Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        resizeDiv();
        $("body").fadeIn(2000);
    }); 
    window.onresize = function(event) {
        resizeDiv();
    }
    function resizeDiv() {
        vph = $(window).height();
        vpw = $(window).width();
        $('.wrapper').css({'height': vph + 'px'});
        $('.wrapper').css({'width': vpw + 'px'});
    }


    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $( this.hash );
                    target = target.length ? target : $( '[name=' + this.hash.slice( 1 ) +']' );
                if ( target.length ) {
                    $( 'html,body' ).animate( { scrollTop: target.offset( ).top }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });


    $(document).ready(function($){
    var parPosition = [];
    $('.par').each(function() {
        parPosition.push($(this).offset().top);
    });
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        var position = $(document).scrollTop(),index;
        for (var i=0; i<parPosition.length; i++) {
            if (position <= parPosition[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        $('.inner')
           .removeClass('active')
           .eq(index)
           .addClass('active');
        }); 
        $('.inner').click(function () {
            $('.inner').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });   
    });
</script>
```